# Split an array of arrays with no key

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using Ajax to submit a form but because I like being complicated I am using JS to allow the end user to add as many input fields to the form as they need. The inputs all have the same name, for example: "val-note[]".

I am making sure the fields results are properly displayed using:

```
$query = strtr($_POST['values'], array('%5B' => '[', '%5D' => ']'));
```

Then I am putting them into arrays:

```
parse_str($query, $newnotes);
```

Then a for each loop:

```
foreach ($newnotes as $notes => $note){
```

However, it outputs an array of arrays. Each array in the arrays is the combined value of each input.
As an example, I have a check box (which is used to delete an input if not needed) the array would be:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "on" [1]=> string(2) "on" [2]=> string(2) "on" [3]=> string(2) "on" }
```

And does this for each input field:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "on" [1]=> string(2) "on" [2]=> string(2) "on" [3]=> string(2) "on" } array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" [3]=> string(1) "4" } array(4) { [0]=> string(10) "iaQDQkl0Dc" [1]=> string(10) "iaQDQkl0Dc" [2]=> string(10) "iaQDQkl0Dc" [3]=> string(10) "iaQDQkl0Dc" } 0
```

What I need to do is be able to be able to select the results for each input so I can put it in the database, but if I try to select a value using:

```
$note[0][1]
```

It gives me only a letter, for example: "n"...

How can I select what I need from this array of arrays?

Comment: Isn't $_POST['values'] of type array? strtr's first argument should be string.

Comment: The output for $_POST['values'] is: 

string(191) "chkbox[]=on&val-note[]=1&jobnumber[]=iaQDQkl0Dc&chkbox[]=on&val-note[]=2&jobnumber[]=iaQDQkl0Dc&chkbox[]=on&val-note[]=3&jobnumber[]=iaQDQkl0Dc&chkbox[]=on&val-note[]=4&jobnumber[]=iaQDQkl0Dc" 0

Comment: $note in your example is array of values (strings). When you call $note[0][1] — you refer second symbol of the first item in array.

Comment: so how do I select one of the strings? It holds 3 strings.

Comment: I suppose you have a few groups of inputs. So for first group:
$newnotes['chkbox'][0], $newnotes['val-note'][0], $newnotes['jobnumber'][0]. For second group: $newnotes['chkbox'][1], $newnotes['val-note'][1], $newnotes['jobnumber'][1]. And so on.

Comment: Dude, you are awesome! Thank you so, so much!